# Cocoa Mac App - Where to save the token?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a Cocoa Mac App with a GitHub login.

The question is quite simple: Where should I store the access token? I want the app to resume after quitting and need a good place to store the token.

Another good question: How could I store the login in my keychain?

Comment: I've used EMKeychain (http://extendmac.com/EMKeychain/) with good success. It's a nice, Objective-C wrapper around the Carbon interface to the Keychain.